# Why am I seeing `SET xmloption = content;` in my structure.sql?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-6

I'm using Rails 6 and recently wrote a small migration to add a column to a table. Simple stuff:

```
class AddInstagramUsernameToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    add_column :users, :instagram_username, :string
  end
end
```

But noticed that I see the following line added to my structure.sql when I run the migration:

`SET xmloption = content;`

I'm not especially worried about it, (admittedly the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/datatype-xml.html) describing the option makes it seem pretty innocuous) but would like not to have such a small migration change any meta postgres stuff. I tried downgrading to Rails 5 to get rid of this line but no luck. I am using postgres version 10.8 and haven't upgraded recently.

Currently I have no idea what's adding this line, and would like to get rid of it if possible. Anyone know what's causing this/how to prevent it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Rails doesn't generate `structure.sql`—it farms that work out to PostgreSQL's built-in pg_dump tool. Per the [Active Record Migrations Rails Guide](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#types-of-schema-dumps):

> When the schema format is set to `:sql`, the database structure will be dumped using a tool specific to the database into `db/structure.sql`. For example, for PostgreSQL, the `pg_dump` utility is used.

It's pg_dump that generates that line in your `structure.sql`.

The reason it does that, as far as I can tell, is that when restoring from a pg_dump file it can't be assumed that the target database has the same `xmloption` set as the source database. Without this line, the user could run into a problem as described in [this bug report](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/153478795159.1302.9617586466368699403@wrigleys.postgresql.org). The change was included in PostgreSQL 9.4.22—specifically [commit 8ba48542](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/commit/8ba485422933e0ae48e8c4e1686ea59cfab75111).

There's no way to disable this, and no reason to do so.

Comment: Coolio. I am satisfied.